# $-\sqrt{k} \sin(kx)$ does not converge even pointwise?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm having small difficulties regarding proving the following:

$$f_k: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$$
$$f_k(x)=-\sqrt{k} \sin(kx), \space k \in \mathbb{N} - \{0\}$$ does not converge even pointwise?

The sequence swings between positive and negative numbers and approaches $\infty$ and $- \infty$.

But is this (divergence) enough to prove that "does not converge even pointwise" or is there perhaps a more finicky proof perhaps demonstrating that there's always some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ for which whenever $k > N$, then the sequence is $> \epsilon$.

Comment: @NickR But the sequence of functions does not converge to a function, at least on most relevant domains.

Comment: @NickR The question does say $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, so it's accurate to say that $f_k(x)$ doesn't converge pointwise.

Comment: One could use the divergence to prove that "there cannot exist a real-valued function $f(x)$ that $f_k(x)$ could converge to", but I'm unsure about how to represent the divergence, when it seems to diverge to both $\infty$ and $- \infty$.

Comment: Also, I think one cannot necessarily see that this couldn't be a conditionally convergent sequence? Positive terms go to $\infty$ and negative terms go to $- \infty$, but the sequence could still converge if it was conditionally convergent.